# Is there a distinct flame-front in a liquid-fuelled rocket combustion chamber?

Tags: rockets, engine-design, liquid-fuel, combustion, combustion-chamber

Liquid fuel and liquid oxidizer are injected at high pressure through small orifices into the 'top' of a rocket's combustion chamber. The intention is that these mix quickly and then burn completely before exiting the combustion chamber and entering the engine bell.  I am wondering if this combustion occurs in a fairly well-behaved manner with a distinct flame-front, a distinct region where the mixture is burning, and a distinct point where the combustion is essentially complete? Or does the whole process necessarily (or inadvertently) involve large-scale turbulence in the combustion chamber - perhaps to ensure adequate mixing and complete combustion?  As a secondary question, how does the combustion behavior change as the engine is throttled?  Is it this behavior that constrains how far a rocket engine can be thottled back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partial answer because

- based on a simulation
- doesn't address the secondary question about changes with throttling

The paper [CFD SIMULATION OF A LIQUID ROCKET PROPELLANT (LH2 /LOx)
COMBUSTION CHAMBER](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255710939_CFD_SIMULATION_OF_A_LIQUID_ROCKET_PROPELLANT_LH_2_LOx_COMBUSTION_CHAMBER) shows a "flame front" in the sense that majority of the combustion reactions take place in a relatively small area of the combustion chamber.

[image]

(zero on the x-axis is the throat)