Is combustion turbulent inside of a rocket engine?
Combustion in a rocket engine is made of diffusion flames in almost all cases. These tend to be turbulent. Rockets which "scream" do so because of the collapse of opposing flame fronts into annihilating "pockets", forming when occurring at a characteristic frequency, an audible thermoacoustic instability. Indeed, velocities are high and characteristic lengths large within a combustion chamber. I imagine Re is in the millions.
However, is the flame front turbulent or is it somehow stable? For rockets which don't scream (or only scream quietly)?

This question also asked about combustion turbulence, but the partial answer does not address that. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49488/6944

One of the classic papers about combustion instability by Crocco and Cheng says "What is certain is that an extremely turbulent condition is always present in the chamber..." but I am not sure that necessarily means the flame front is.

First, I have to say how much I appreciate your well-researched question!
By design, a lot of mixing of the reactants must take place in the combustion chamber to ensure that rapid combustion occurs without combustion instability. You can learn more about the geometry of the flame front from this answer and that answer supports the idea that most of the reaction occurs within a fairly confined region.
The difference between laminar flow and turbulent flow has to do with the degree to which there is mixing in the stream. There is a lot of mixing of the reactants going on ahead of the flame front - again, this is by design. (Also see Organic Marble's comment on the question about the Crocco and Cheng paper). Thus, ahead of the flame front, there is turbulent flow.
The rocket exhaust from a properly functioning rocket engine tends to look very clean; therefore, one might speculate that sometime after the flame front, flow is laminar. But let's take a closer look...
Below is a series of sequential images of Starship IFT3's rocket exhaust taken at 2400 FPS. These particular frames show a visually trackable combustion event (if anyone knows of the technical term for these events, please let me know in the comments.) This trackable combustion diffused rapidly - on the order of 9 frames, or $9/2400=0.00375 seconds$. So, this suggests that the flow after the flame front is, in fact, also turbulent.
Since we can establish through logic and empirical evidence that the flow before and after the flame front is turbulent, then I think it would be reasonable to assume that the flow within the flame front itself is also turbulent. Technically we're using circumstantial evidence to arrive at this conclusion, but I can't think of a good reason why the flow would transition from turbulent to laminar and then back to turbulent again.

